# C3JS bar display alignment

Tags: javascript, d3.js, c3.js

Team,

Q1 : I have a bar graph (on x-axis i have timestamps, and on y-axis i have few counts). Now, the bar display is not aligned with x-axis label display, it is misaligned and thus does not show the bar display at correct position of label value.

I tried with tick value as false\true, but still the bar is misaligned. Any idea as where it is going wrong?

Q2: For the same bar graph above, i wish to show the summary\count of all counts inside a legend, are there any examples or which call back function to achieve this?

Regards,
Santhosh

Comment: Can you make a fiddle for us?

Comment: So, for Q2: Here is something as an example, http://jsfiddle.net/k9Dbf/660/ I wanted total of bar counts in legend as summary.

Comment: Team, any body on this?

Comment: It's not a great solution, but it works :) [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k9Dbf/665/)

Comment: Thanks PDKnight it gets to start  with something, how do we display this total as part of legend on top\below the chart, (or) to say display upload% and download% as part of legend somewhere? As well, any idea why the alignment of bars is uneven sometimes?

Comment: Can you please show me, what you want to get? What do you think with "aligment of bars is uneven sometimes"?

Comment: Hi PDKnit:  so for the alignment of bars, i resolved it, here the spacing between bars under a bar graph was uneven, because its  a timeseries bar graph and dates are wide apart, and so the bars were displaying too much of distance, i fixed this issue, but for the other question, where the summary (total) i want to display it as legend text, rather the tool tip, any example for that?

Comment: So, to keep it simple, i just wanted to display the total upload%, download% in a legend at the top right corner. I found few examples but not completely enough to know as how to submit the percentages text under this legend.

Comment: Where's the legend? You mean the "hover" one?

Comment: Something like this at the right \top-right corner: http://www.numeruscloud.com/ChartDirector/doc/cdphpdoc/stackedbar.html. C3 js does provides custom legend but its not taking the text (EX: upload or download %) to display?

Comment: The page is not available :(

Comment: Look at figure2 here(at the top left corner there is a rectangle box with some legend) http://abacus.bates.edu/~ganderso/biology/resources/writing/HTWtablefigs.html. So, iam not sure if tough to understand, i just want to display percentage of all counts in a legend, EX: Imagine iam displaying profits and losses over few years(years being along x-axis and profits\losses along x-axis). Here, i want to show net profit\loss over the years in a legend at top.

Comment: Finally, thanks for explanation :D I would make a **legend** element and run the function when creating the graph to display the **legend** :)